# Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation - install

Tags: python3

What is the problem here please? I try to install https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/

```
sudo pip3 install --user python3-xlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
    os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_pip3.0.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Installing another program using pip3 leads to an error:

```
pip3 install python3-tk
Collecting python3-tk
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-tk
```

Comment: Do you get the same error trying to install anorher package using pip3?

Comment: It gave error as well, but maybe another kind. I added it to my question

Comment: Hum: doesn't help... (pip3 working for any package at all?) You could try to reinstall pip3 with this script: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py ???

Comment: Thank you and before reinstalling, how to test pip3 that it really doesn't work? I have no idea what package should I install.

Comment: try: pip3 install requests

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.18.4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see `python3-tk` is not an available package from [Pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=Python3-tk) so the second error is "normal".

For the first one, you mixed a `sudo` call with the `--user` flags. I do not really know the internals of `pip` but try to remove one of them: either `sudo pip install` or `pip install --user`.